# Flutter send image in Navigator.pop result object

Tags: image, flutter

I am new for flutter development. I want to send a signature of a user when it user press OK. I am converting signature to Image but unable to send the image on Navigator.pop result object.

Comment: Please provide additional info such as error log if any and problematic part of your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can save the `image` in local storage and return its name